# Sneaky '\n' in a python string

Tags: python, linux, cross-platform

I have a python application written in 2.7

It works perfectly on my local windows 10 machine, but it has a bag on the remote Linux Debian server. More specifically

Here is a piece of code in question:

```
    elif teacher_num:
      data = requests.get('https://table.nsu.ru/ics/teacher/' + teacher_num).text
      teacher_name = (re.findall(r"<h1>.+</h1>",requests.get('https://table.nsu.ru/teacher/' + teacher_num).text[3000:7000])[0])[4:-5]
```

It takes the string `teacher_num`, concatenates it with the URL, and makes a request. As I have said it does what I expect on my local machine, but on a remote server, it treats `teacher_num` in a strange way and the URL becomes invalid.

After hours I figure out that there is `'\n'` in the `teacher_num` string that I can't see... But why is it ok on my local machine but is not on the Linux Debian server? Is that some specific feature of this system?

Comment: How did `teacher_num` get assigned? If this code is executed on two different machines the difference in data source on the machines may be the culprit for the issue. It would be useful to include the relevant code that ultimately assigned that variable.

Comment: based on the limited information provided, I guess you should try to do the following
```new_teacher_num = teacher_num.replace("\n", "\\n")```, now use this new_teacher_num instead of teacher_num

Comment: Also note that newline may be different between Windows and Linux